# SpringBoot Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I am currently writing an API backend using Spring which I deploy on to a DEV server using Spring Boot.

If I run the backend in STS compiling to a jar (specified in Maven), and using Tomcat 8, it runs without a problem.

However as I want to deploy to the server I am using Spring Boot.

Application.java:

```
        package com.nsshell.supervisory.controller;
    
        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
        import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan; 
    
        @SpringBootApplication
        @ComponentScan({"com.nsshell.supervisory"})
        public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
            @Overide
            protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                return application.sources(Application.class);
            }
    
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            }
    
        }
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>NinjaServer</artifactId>
    <name>webservice</name>
    <description>Absence Tracking System</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <springVersion>5.2.21.RELEASE</springVersion>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.76</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId></groupId>
            <artifactId></artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.22.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.10.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin for Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Project-Version>${project.version}</Project-Version>
                            <SCM-Repository>${GIT_URL}</SCM-Repository>
                            <SCM-Path>${GIT_BRANCH}</SCM-Path>
                            <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                            <SCM-CommittedRevision>${buildNumber}</SCM-CommittedRevision>
                            <SCM-CommittedDate>${timestamp}</SCM-CommittedDate>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

maven generates a spring-boot version of 1.5.9.Release

my application-dev.properties is as below :

```
# DB properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://YSE0-D45D0101/SNEO_TFG0;instance=IN01;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2
spring.datasource.username=sneo
spring.datasource.password=sneo
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

When I deploy my code to my dev server, I get the below stacktrace:

```
[main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in classpath resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
[main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Stopping service [Tomcat]
....
.... 
[main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in classpath resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~ [spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:637) ~ [spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.22.RELEASE]
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        at com.rbc.rbccm.supervisory.controller.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes!/:2.0.18]
        ......
        ......
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [rest-ws-2.0.18.jar:2.0.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [rest-ws-2.0.18.jar:2.0.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [rest-ws-2.0.18.jar:2.0.18]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~ [spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate (ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~ [spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.22.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:450) ~ [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver (WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:947) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.21.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.21.RELEASE]
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~ [spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar!/5.2.22.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I looked at the spring documentation and other resources, couldnt figure out the fix for this!

Comment: You are mixing versions of Spring Boot and Spring that you shouildn't be mixing. You are using Spring Boot but are doing everything to work around it (including excessive dependencies, including the `maven-jar-plugin` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the list of dependencies and the incompatible versions you are using.

You are using Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE which requires Spring Framework 4.1.x (you included 5.2.x which is the source of your problems). To use Spring 5.2 you need to use Spring Boot 2.2.

To properly use Spring Boot use the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies to get the proper dependencies. This will also reduce your list of dependencies needed to declare.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>NinjaServer</artifactId>
    <name>webservice</name>
    <description>Absence Tracking System</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.10.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin for Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Project-Version>${project.version}</Project-Version>
                            <SCM-Repository>${GIT_URL}</SCM-Repository>
                            <SCM-Path>${GIT_BRANCH}</SCM-Path>
                            <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                            <SCM-CommittedRevision>${buildNumber}</SCM-CommittedRevision>
                            <SCM-CommittedDate>${timestamp}</SCM-CommittedDate>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This will give you the same (more or less) dependencies with a lot less work. I would also suggest to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.6 or even 2.7 instead of using an old unsupported version (both 1.2 and 2.2. aren't supported anymore).

**NOTE:** your logging is a bit weird as you have both Log4j2 and Logback on your classpath, so I'm not sure which you want to use. Spring Boot will default to Logback if found.

Comment: thanks Martin! I see where I messed up here